# Passing data from activity to BroadcastReceiver causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have a BroadcastReceiver which gets data from Activity by Intent,
with PendingIntent.

Send data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(addOne.this,AlarmReceiver.class);

intent.putExtra("msg", title.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("note", note.getText().toString());
int id =...;

PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

Get data:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context2, Intent intent) {

       String msg=intent.getStringExtra("msg");
       String title=intent.getStringExtra("msg");
       ...
}
```

When onReceive is called i get a NullPointerException.

My BroadcastReceiver-manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Have you debug and check whether your getting data in msg and title string or not.

Comment: I am not getting data i am getting NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Make your pending intent like below line and try

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: what is the exact problem?? Are you getting data in msg and title string of broadcast reciever

Comment: have you declared & initialize title and note where you are creating pending intent.

Comment: I have tested your code and its working you might have not initialize your title and note

Comment: No i am not getting string msg and title , i am getting error NULL  and i know you think it work but try close the app before alarm working...

Comment: Have you declared and initialize your title and not edittext or textview whatever it is

Comment: yes i declared. i think the problem is the intent...if the time for example is hour later there isn't activity that call to the receiver-there is not intent,you understand?

Comment: I was solving your problem and your answering me